# Login to google reader using android account manager

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, accountmanager, google-reader

I am in a Android project of creating a Google Reader client.
I with to use built in account credential and to be as close of the official google reader app on that point.

I'm struggling in a problem since a week and can't find out how to solve it.
I managed to get an Auth Token from AccountManager using authtokentype "reader".
The token is of the form

```
DQAAAOcAAACJAmAkHEpPnaP-v7HxPYyz3XtCNwTiFLUsqYXfLQvCko4AqUyY213U81fXeNZC3VVArBaEsJJFcRXDmczrEhDquxiJiWSp7eM9T8Bs2VV3uqFwE7irrfarKyBH-oVn2nZxKc3wcugqa7k3p4KCotz48cQRslDQhSZj1AK4hxqO2eu5X8lutffRCPjA6kmgmXhkYA4RuTCxVXbZr0E_ytQteX2VzOlPbqrZ7QD7NiqbeJYODE3pk4BNjHTWtgXAr3J0U7LMdtRh9aC9AJoBp1SNl3jptyzqFfeEjWtVTBQlKtn40vyzMDt0sZoSIaSPquc
```

Now that I have the token, how do I login with the unofficial Google Reader api ?
I know [this](http://code.google.com/p/greader-unofficial/) java api, and found various documentation [here](http://undoc.in/googlereader.html), [here](http://code.google.com/p/pyrfeed/wiki/GoogleReaderAPI) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-reader-api/wiki/Authentication). All of these only lay the emphasis upon Client Login with email and password. Each time I find a code sample it is of the form

```
token = someFunctionIAlreadyUse();
someUndocumentedUnknowPersonalFunction(token);
```

Am I missing a simple way ? If not where can I find a detailled way of accessing the api (in java) ?

Answer (score 0):

Just finding out how to do. The token given by android is the same as the token used in the regular google reader authentication. Here is some code from Christian Dadswell using Jsoup and modified to work with the Android authtoken :

```
public static String getGoogleToken(String authKey) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException
{
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(_TOKEN_URL).header("Authorization", _AUTHPARAMS + authKey).userAgent(_USER_AGENT).timeout(4000).get();

    // RETRIEVES THE RESPONSE TOKEN
    String _TOKEN = doc.body().text();
    return _TOKEN;
}
```

and

```
public static String getUserInfo(String authKey) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException
{
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(_USER_INFO_URL).header("Authorization", _AUTHPARAMS + authKey).userAgent(_USER_AGENT).timeout(4000).get();

    // RETRIEVES THE RESPONSE USERINFO
    String _USERINFO = doc.body().text();
    return _USERINFO;
}
```

And constants :

```
private static String _USER_AGENT = "YourAppNameHere";

private static final String _AUTHPARAMS = "GoogleLogin auth=";
private static final String _GOOGLE_LOGIN_URL = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin";
private static final String _READER_BASE_URL = "http://www.google.com/reader/";
private static final String _API_URL = _READER_BASE_URL + "api/0/";
private static final String _TOKEN_URL = _API_URL + "token";
private static final String _USER_INFO_URL = _API_URL + "user-info";
private static final String _USER_LABEL = "user/-/label/";
private static final String _TAG_LIST_URL = _API_URL + "tag/list";
private static final String _EDIT_TAG_URL = _API_URL + "tag/edit";
private static final String _RENAME_TAG_URL = _API_URL + "rename-tag";
private static final String _DISABLE_TAG_URL = _API_URL + "disable-tag";
private static final String _SUBSCRIPTION_URL = _API_URL + "subscription/edit";
private static final String _SUBSCRIPTION_LIST_URL = _API_URL + "subscription/list";
```